# Microoptimization: iterating with local variable vs. class member

Tags: c++, micro-optimization

I thought I will save some time if I declare iterating variable once as a class member:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  void method1() {
    for(i=0; i<A; ++i) ...
  }
  void method2() {
    for(i=0; i<B; ++i) ...
  }
} foo;
```

however, this seems to be cca 20% faster

```
struct Foo {
  void method1() {
    for(int i=0; i<A; ++i) ...
  }
  void method2() {
    for(int i=0; i<B; ++i) ...
  }
} foo;
```

in this code

```
void loop() { // Arduino loops
  foo.method1();
  foo.method2();
}
```

Can you explain the performance difference?

(I need to run many simple paralel "processes" on Arduino where such microoptimalization makes a difference.)

Comment: "will save some time if I declare iterating variable once as a class member". A very strange idea, that. It's `this->i` every time.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the local counter variable is only ever stored in a register, but to **know** these things, compile with `-save-temps` and look at the assembly. Are `A` and `B` smaller than 256? Then the compiler might be able to use an 8-bit int (faster on an 8-bit MCU) in the local case. All is guesswork.

Comment: The idea was not to allocate additional stack space and save an instruction per call. The `...` does many different things, but the `i` is used as array index lower than 256 (byte size).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare your loop variable inside a loop, it is scoped very narrowly. The compiler is free to keep it in a register all the time, so it does not get committed to memory even once.

When you declare your loop variable as an instance variable, the compiler has no such flexibility. It must keep the variable in memory, in case some of your methods would want to examine its state. For example, if you do this in your first code example

```
void method2() {
    for(i=0; i<B; ++i) { method3(); }
}
void method3() {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

the value of `i` in `method3` must be changing as the loop progresses. The compiler has no way around committing all its side effects to memory. Moreover, it cannot assume that `i` stayed the same when you come back from `method3`, further increasing the number of memory accesses.

Dealing with updates in memory requires a lot more CPU cycles than performing updates to register-based variables. That is why it is always a good idea to keep your loop variables scoped down to the loop level.

Comment: Is it a good idea to declare `for(register int i=0; ... )` then? Assuming pre C++11 standard where `register` specifier was not deprecated.

Comment: It was deprecated for a reason, and the reason is that it's completely useless today.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you explain the performance difference?

The most plausible explanation I could come up for this performance difference is:

*Data member* `i` is declared on the global memory, which cannot be kept in the register all the time, hence operations on it would be way slower than on the *loop variable* `i` due to a very broad scope (The data member `i` has to cater for all the member functions of the class).

@DarioOO adds:

> In addition the compiler is not free to store it temporary in a
>   register because `method3()` could throw an exception leaving the object
>   in a unwanted state (because theoretically no one prevent to you to
>   write 
>   `int k=this->i; for(k=0;k<A;k++)method3(); this->i=k;`. That code
>   would be almost as fast as local variable but you have to keep into
>   account when `method3()` throws (I believe when there is the guarantee it
>   does not throw the compiler will optimize that with `-O3` or `-O4` to be
>   verified)

Comment: In addition the compiler is not free to store it temporary in a register because `method3()` could throw an exception leaving the object in a unwanted state (because theorically no one prevent to you to write `int k=this->i; for(k=0;k<A;k++)method3(); this->i=k;` That code would be almost as fast as local variable but you have to keep into account when method3 throws (i believe when there is the guarantee it does not throw the compiler will optimize that with -O3 or -O4. to be verified

Comment: Oh sorry :) I ddin't wanted to correct you. I'm used to add my thoughts to answers just because I like writing about programming. by the way +1 for quick response :D